# PTFE coating - how? Alternatively, lowering surface energy

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Another part of our experimental setup requires me to lower the surface energy of a small sealed hollow glass sphere (30mm dia) in order to minimize adsorption.
Any idea how I can do this? There seem to be some PTFE sprays, but how well do they adhere to (fragile) glass? Any alternatives ideas?

Comment: More details on the experiment? It seems to me that you have the experiment wrong. I suspect you're trying to change the surface tension.

Comment: Measuring density changes in gas using the buoyancy of a glass sphere and a microbalance. Unless the glass is heated between measurements adsorption can skew the results if density change is low.